# Can't get connected to my remote server through a proxy with NX Client

Tags: proxy, connection, nx-client

I'm trying NX Client for Linux (Ubuntu) to get connected to my remote server.
It works fine with the base connection.

But in some places, I can't get access to the internet. So, I plug my phone to my PC with a USB cable and turn it into a modem (I change the proxy settings to 'localhost:8080' in my laptop system).

So, the problem is that the NX Client throws me this message each time I try to access to my remote server (even If I checked `Connect through a HTTP proxy`):

```
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 2721
NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command
NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files
NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options
NX> 200 Connected to web proxy at address: 127.0.0.1 on port: 8080
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

Thank you,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it - your laptop is not a proxy server. Of course it will close the connection if NX tries to connect.

Don't use a proxy server. Or get the appropriate proxy server if there is one on your phone's data plan.